# Find smallest possible degree of $f(x)$ from given conditions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, functional-equations

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of *degree strictly less than 100* and such that it does not have $x^3-x$ as a factor. If
$$\frac{d^{100}}  {dx^{100}}  \left(\frac{p(x)}{x^3-x}\right)=\frac{f(x)} {g(x)}$$ for some polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Then, find the smallest possible degree of $f(x)$.

Here $$\frac{d^{100}}{dx^{100}}$$ means taking $100$th* derivative.

**My attempt**

$$\frac{p(x)}{x^3-x}=q(x) +\frac{r(x)} {x^3-x}$$
Then, if $p(x)$ has degree strictly less than 100 then it may be of 99 or 98 or something like that. But if it is like that then its 100th derivative will be zero.

As in case of $x^2$ its first derivative is $2x$, then its second derivative is *2* and then the third derivative is 0. So, if f(x) is nth degree polynomial its n+1 derivative is 0. But then it does not satisfies the given conditions.

Edit: The test solution gives another answer of 200 with another solution giving 0 as answer. Now how can two least possible degrees can be the solution

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading, but if you take $p(x)=x^2-1$, then $\frac {p(x)}{x^3-x}=\frac 1x$, no?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Long division and partial fraction decomposition produce
$${p(x)\over x^3-x}=q(x)+{A\over x}+{B\over x-1}+{C\over x+1}\ ,$$
with $q$ a polynomial of degree $\leq96$ and $A$, $B$, $C$ constants, not all of them $=0$. Now $A=1$, $B=C=0$ is possible. In this case
$${d^{100}\over dx^{100}}\left({p(x)\over x^3-x}\right)={100!\over x^{101}}\ .$$
The answer to the question therefore is $0$.

Comment: *How* and *Why* did you chose A=1,B=C=0? And **Thank You** for clearing my doubt.

Comment: In order to obtain an $f$ with smallest possible degree.

Comment: But the same can be obtained by A=0 B=0 and C=1 giving $$\frac{100!}{(x+1)^{100}}$$

Comment: @jayant98:  true, but that gives the same answer.  The given answer justifies that the degree of $f$ can be $0$ and no lower degree is possible.